# How can I add No Response Required in an Oulook meeting invite?

Tags: outlook, invite, meeting-request

How can I add No Response Required button in an Outlook meeting invite? I know there are Response options but on the meeting invites that I send with Response options disabled the Accept/Decline buttons are always displayed. Please review captures below:

**Desired Meeting Invite - Notice 'No Response Required' button displays**

[image: Current behavior]

**Current Meeting Invite - Notice Accept/Decline buttons still displaying.**

[image: Expected behavior]

How can I send a meeting invite using Outlook to just display a "No Response Required" button as shown in the first screen shot above.? Note that I have set No Response Required option.

Comment: The difference between these meetings is that the first one was accepted while the second not.